# AngularJS: how to generate dynamic ng-model for input type = text

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My current scenario is: I've doing nesting repetition like follow:

```
<form name="task_form" ng-app="myApp" ng-submit="tasksubmit()">    
 <ul class="items-list">
      <li ng-repeat="task in taskslist | orderBy:orderProp">
      <p>
        <strong>{{task.title}}</strong>
      </p>
      <input type="text" ng-model="task.input_value">
     </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

If in `tasklist` array i have 100+ tasks then it means i have more then 100 same `ng-model` values for `<input type=text>`. Here problem is that how can i get the values for `<input type = text>` against any `task.id` so that i can use those input values for my further use.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an object - make the `task.id` as the key:

```
$scope.taskValues = {};
```

And the view:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="taskValues[task.id]">
```

Comment: and how will i get the inputed value sir?

Comment: @TechKid -- Depends when you need it - you can loop over `taskValues` anytime - or you can attach a `ngChange` event to each `input` and grab the value at the time of typing

Comment: Sir, can you please help with making plunker or fiddle, 
I actually want to get the `input values` along with `task.id` on the time of form submittion..

Comment: @TechKid -- you can do `for (var taskID in $scope.taskValues) { console.log($scope.taskValues[taskID] }`