# AngularJS: how to generate dynamic ng-model for input type [text]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My current scenario is: I've doing nesting repetition like follow:

```
<form name="task_form" ng-app="myApp" ng-submit="tasksubmit()">    
 <ul class="items-list">
      <li ng-repeat="task in taskslist | orderBy:orderProp">
      <p>
        <strong>{{task.title}}</strong>
      </p>
      <input type="text" ng-model="task_input_values[task.id]" >
     </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

If in `tasklist` array i have 100+ `tasks` then it means i have more then 100 same `ng-model` values for `<input type=text>`. Here im using `ng-model="task_input_values[task.id]"` it give me the array like `{"14":"sometext here"}`  i dont know how to capture the `id` that is `14` and `input value` that is `sometext here`. Moreover, if u have any better logic please help me. I'm newbie in angularJS.

Comment: can u please be more specific what you are trying to achieve. Example would be nice

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here in myy case im getting this array `{"14":"sometext here"}` from `ng-model="task_input_values[task.id]" ` please help me how to get the key and text from array that is generated by this `ng-model`

Comment: Can you give us an output of at least 10 elements ? Your question is really confusing ! I would like to answer it but it's impossible to understand your problem. See below - my answer. But apparently it doesn't satisfy you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS: how to generate dynamic ng-model for input type = text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34635273/angularjs-how-to-generate-dynamic-ng-model-for-input-type-text)

Answer (score 0):

You can edit directely the object you are iterate :

```
<form name="task_form" ng-app="myApp" ng-submit="tasksubmit()">    
 <ul class="items-list">
      <li ng-repeat="task in taskslist | orderBy:orderProp">
      <p>
        <strong>{{task.title}}</strong>
      </p>
      <input type="text" ng-model="task.title" >
     </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

See live demo: [live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bneiluj/y66m5dLc/)
You just need to use your `tasks` variable as an array of objects:

```
$scope.taskslist = [ 
     {title: "I am first text input"}, 
     {title: "I am second text input"} 
    ];
```

and then bind to the value property of the object in the ngRepeat:

```
<form name="task_form" ng-app="myApp" ng-submit="tasksubmit()">    
     <ul class="items-list">
         <li ng-repeat="task in taskslist | orderBy:orderProp">
            <p>
               <strong>{{task.title}}</strong>
            </p>
            <input type="text" ng-model="task.title" >
         </li>
     </ul>
</form>
```

Since `tasks` is an array - you don't need to specify the id as `tasks[$index]` give you the value of the title ;) Ex: `tasks[1]` gives you:
`{text: "I am second text input"}`